# UITableViewDelegate methods

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uitableview

Here is an xcode project that I just did to ask this question:

http://www.mediafire.com/?z26ufsfhby62br9

Open the log and run it. You will find that it outputs `display: x` and `create: x` where x is a number 0 to 49 and corresponds to the cell of the same number. It should only output to 22 before any scrolling is performed as Apple are always boasting that their tableviews are loaded as needed.

It basically shows that `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` and `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` are fired for each cell pretty much as soon as the tableview appears, why is this?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"create: %i", indexPath.row);
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                                       reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
   willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell 
 forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"display: %i", indexPath.row);   
}
```

Why are the above meothds called just after the tableView loads (and just before each cell appears)? Surely they should be called just before each cell appears only?

Comment: When I run it without touching anything, only the first 23 rows are displayed (from 0 to 22) and the logs confirm that only 23 cells are created and shown. This is on Simulator, 4.2, latest SDK.

Comment: For some reason it only does 23 onwards when the simulator is the active window.

Comment: I added the mentioned methods from your code.

Comment: my last line: `2010-12-14 02:02:32.764 tableviewtest[37088:207] display: 22`. Always the same — no matter if active window or waiting several minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your table view is reloading before it actually fully displays, that could cause the behavior you're seeing. Then the cells would get initialized, prepared for display, but then all of that would be lost (before even shown on screen) as the table is reloaded.

Comment: why would it be reloading before it fully displays?

Comment: If you're calling `reloadData` in any place, or changing the data source, or changing the frame, or really doing anything at all to the table view after it's already prepared its cells for display. The bottom line is that you can't really expect it to *NOT* reload its data, and thus your code should always behave correctly in such a case.

Answer (score 1):

These are the default delegate methods.. This will be be called for each cell everytime.

You use `willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` to configure things like font and text color. In the newer version of the iPhone, with certain table configurations, if you configure things like the label text color in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`  method, your changes will be lost at some point before the cell is actually displayed. Here you can do things like change the label's color, adjust background highlighting, such things as these.

Comment: No, I know what they are and do and when to use them. However I don't know why they are called for a cell when the cell is not being displayed

Comment: For me its displaying 0 to 22 only

Comment: For me it does the 22+ after a delay.